# What branch of mathematics does coordinate systems belong to?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm a high school student and I'm new to mathematics involving coordinates, especially polar coordinate systems and cartesian coordinate systems.

Comment: It is possible to define a topology in almost any set which defines a neighborhood of any point (element) of the set and allows to speak of limit (which is unique when the topology is separated, when it is not separated then the limit is not unique) what is proper to mathematical analysis. A Cartesian coordinate system is a reference system for the position of points, which allows the use of algebraic methods for the treatment of geometry.

Comment: If topology would be "modded out" in mathematics then the cartesian coordinate system would not vanish. So the answer is: no, you cannot call  the cartesian coordinate system a "part of topology".

Answer (score 2):

Coordinate systems are not a part of topology, but the (topological) *dimension* of a space is. Coordinates are a way to transform geometry into algebra and/or analysis.

Answer (score 1):

@Henno's answer is in many ways perfect; the second sentence in particular distills something I only understood many years after getting my Ph.D., alas. That also means that it may not be completely enlightening for a beginner. At the risk of adding to confusion, let me say a little more:

"Part of" isn't exactly a well-defined notion in mathematics. We use whatever tools are appropriate to get results. In topology, we tend to think of ourselves as "knowing" about $\Bbb R^n$ (we have a lot of useful theorems about the real line, plane, etc.). If we're studying some space $X$ and can find, say, a (nice) correspondence between some subset $V \subset X$ and an open set $U \subset \Bbb R^n$, then we feel we've got an understanding of $V$: it "looks like a bit of Euclidean space." And we might even use coordinates on Euclidean space to say something about points of $V$. So while "coordinate systems" are not part of topology, there are plenty of places in topology books (esp. differential topology books) where you'll see them appear.

Answer (score 0):

Via a cartesian coordinate system ( in a Euclidean space)You are able to define a distance, say You have points $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\cdot\\x_n\end{pmatrix},y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\\cdot\\y_n\end{pmatrix}$ given in cartesian coordinates ( in an $n$-dimensional space) their distance is ( for example) given by
$$d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2}$$
and now You may say a set $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\textbf{open}$ if for every point $x\in M$ there is a disk $D_{\varepsilon}(x)$ contained in $M$:
$$D_{\varepsilon}(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\subset M.$$
Now by saying which sets are $\textbf{open}$ You define a topology on a set. This is why this notion is called $\textbf{intrinsic}$. This is just one way how cartesian coordinates can be used to define a topology. So there is a link between coordinates and topology, one couldn't say they are part of it, though it is not clear what that is supposed to mean
.